# Issue with using pyqtgraph

Tags: python

I am trying to use pyqtgraph for a project, and I have installed pyqtgraph, pyqt5, and pyqtwebengine. But when I try to call
`from pyqtgraph.Qt.QtGui import QApplication`
It does not work and gives me the error "ImportError: No module named pyqtgraph.Qt.QtGui", I have tried updating pip and reinstalling all the other libraries.

Comment: Install Python version 3.7 or below as you may be facing the issue of the 
time module not having the clock function. So first get the version right, and then `pip install pyqtgraph==0.10.0`

Comment: Just gave this a try and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Does the import via pyqt5 work, i.e. `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`?